# Haproxy set header and path for a incoming https request

Tags: ssl, url-rewriting, haproxy

I have a domain name https://abc.example.com/a/b/c, I have to convert the URL to https://example.com/abc/a/b/c

To achieve it I have done below configuration in the frontend

```
mode http
http-request set-var(req.rewrite_repo) req.hdr(host),lower,regsub(\.example\.com$,) if { hdr_end(host) -i .example.com }
http-request set-path %[var(req.rewrite_repo)]/v2%[path] if { var(req.rewrite_repo) -m found }
http-request set-header Host example.verizon.com if { var(req.rewrite_repo) -m found }
```

Now if I give http://abc.example.com it is working fine. But if I give https://abc.example.com it is not working. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: This config should not differentiate, but you need it in the right place.  If you have it in a `frontend` that only handles HTTP, there's your trouble.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot. I have this configuration in my frontend.  I have even tried this from backend and it also not picking up https request.